# Gorm multiple Preloadings don't work

Tags: go, go-gorm

Good Monday Morning everyone!
I am having a problem with preloading entities! I am doing multiple preloadings of entities. The `Country`entity is working fine, but the `Report` is not being preloaded. Any ideas what might be causing that?

```
type Review struct {
  ID             int
  Report   Report 'gorm:"ForeignKey:ReportId"'
  ReportId uint
  Country        Country      'gorm:"ForeignKey:CountryId"'
  CountryId      uint
}
func FindApprovedReviews(page int, countryId int) ([]Review, int, error) {
  var reviews [] Review

// Subtract one to fix Offset but keep page number correct
  page -= 1
  err := db.Where("approved_at IS NOT NULL").
//TODO: Change this to a configuration file value
      Limit(10).
      Where("approved_by IS NOT NULL").
      Where("country_id = ?", countryId).
//TODO: Change this (the 10) to a configuration value
      Offset(page * 10).
      Order("id desc").
      Preload("Report").
      Preload("Country").
      Find(&reviews).
      Error
  if err != nil {
      return nil, 0, err
  }

  return reviews, count, err
}
```

The two related structs (`Country` and `Report`) are simply made up of `gorm.Model` for teting purpose.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

EDIT: I am using the `mysql` driver.

P.S. The `[...]` represent business data that has been hidden, but they are simple columns that are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just realised I was selecting queries where the relation (i.e. FK) with the `Report` table was null.

Works fine if the relation key is not null.